Directory copy from AWS S3 Bucket to Azure Storage using Azure Databricks
I am trying to copy a directory from AWS s3 bucket to Azure storage exploree using python (Python 3.11.0) in azure databricks.
import urllib3
import boto3
from azure.storage.blob import BlobServiceClient
from boto3.session import Session
import os
import botocore
from smart_open import open as smart_open
 
def copy_directory_from_s3_to_blob(s3_bucket, s3_prefix, aws_access_key_id, aws_secret_access_key, azure_connection_string, azure_container):
    # Create an S3 client with AWS access key
    s3_client = boto3.client('s3', aws_access_key_id=aws_access_key_id, aws_secret_access_key=aws_secret_access_key)
    print(s3_client)
    # List all objects in the S3 directory
    response = s3_client.list_objects_v2(Bucket=s3_bucket, Prefix=s3_prefix)
    print('response')
    # Create a BlobServiceClient using the Azure connection string
    blob_service_client = BlobServiceClient.from_connection_string(azure_connection_string)
    # Get a reference to the Azure container
    container_client = blob_service_client.get_container_client(azure_container)
    # Iterate over each object in the S3 directory
    for obj in response.get('Contents', []):
        # Download the file from S3 using smart_open for direct streaming
        s3_key = obj['Key']
        temp_file_path = f'/tmp/{os.path.basename(s3_key)}'
        with smart_open(f's3://{s3_bucket}/{s3_key}', 'rb', transport_params={
            'session': boto3.Session(aws_access_key_id=aws_access_key_id, aws_secret_access_key=aws_secret_access_key)
        }) as s3_file:
            # Upload the file to Azure Blob Storage
            blob_client = container_client.get_blob_client(blob=s3_key)
            blob_client.upload_blob(data=s3_file, overwrite=True)
    return "Directory copied successfully!"
 
# Example usage
s3_bucket = 'bucket_name'
s3_prefix = 'bucket_prefix/'  # Adjusted prefix to not include leading slash
aws_access_key_id = 'access_keyid'
aws_secret_access_key = 'secret_Access_key'
azure_connection_string = 'connection_string'
azure_container = 'container_name'
result = copy_directory_from_s3_to_blob(s3_bucket, s3_prefix, aws_access_key_id, aws_secret_access_key, azure_connection_string, azure_container)
print(result)

But I am getting the below error, from network side I have opened the firewall. Is there anything I have missed to configure?
Error
SSLError: SSL validation failed for https://test.s3.amazonaws.com/?list-type=2&prefix=test%2F&encoding-type=url TLS/SSL connection has been closed (EOF) (_ssl.c:992)
File /databricks/python/lib/python3.11/site-packages/urllib3/connectionpool.py:714, in HTTPConnectionPool.urlopen(self, method, url, body, headers, retries, redirect, assert_same_host, timeout, pool_timeout, release_conn, chunked, body_pos, **response_kw)
    713 # Make the request on the httplib connection object.
--> 714 httplib_response = self._make_request(
    715     conn,
    716     method,
    717     url,
    718     timeout=timeout_obj,
    719     body=body,
    720     headers=headers,
    721     chunked=chunked,
    722 )
    724 # If we're going to release the connection in ``finally:``, then
    725 # the response doesn't need to know about the connection. Otherwise
    726 # it will also try to release it and we'll have a double-release
    727 # mess. 


Does it work if you actually download the file to the /tmp/ directory and then perform an upload (without using smart_open())? Since you're already calling AWS APIs to list the bucket, you could simply download it instead of calling .get(). You're not saving any part of the process by using smart_open().
